# Comparing 2 different set of data array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an app that are retrieving 2 sets of data. Now I want to do is get the `brand` of `data1` and and the `brand` of `data2` which depends on the date, if true it will render the `amount` of `data2`.

so far this is my code

-my data

```js
const data1 = [
{
  "data1result": [
    {
      "brand": "brand1"
    },
    {
      "brand": "brand2"
    },
    {
      "brand": "brand3"
    },
    {
      "brand": "brand4"
    }
  ]
}  
];

const data2 = [
{
  "data2result": [
    {
      "date": "12-01",
      "details": [
        {
          "amount": 24250,
          "brand": "brand1"
        },
        {
          "amount": 68350,
          "brand": "brand2"
        },
        {
          "amount": 60,
          "brand": "brand3"
        },
        {
          "amount": 11078,
          "brand": "brand4"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "date": "12-02",
      "details": [
        {
          "amount": 27340,
          "brand": "brand1"
        },
        {
          "amount": 16500,
          "brand": "brand2"
        },
        {
          "amount": 210,
          "brand": "brand3"
        },
        {
          "amount": 23229,
          "brand": "brand4"
        }
      ]
    },
    ]
}
];
```

and as for my code

```js
export default React.createClass({

  render() {
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
           <th></th>
           {
               data1.map(function(i) {
                 return <th>{i.data1result.brand}</th>;
               })
             }
       </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
         {data2.map(function(a) {

           return (
             <tr className="salesTarget">
                 <td className="td-fixed"><b>{a.data2result.date}</b></td>
                      //help me here
                 <td className="td-fixed">brand1 amount of date **-**</td>
                 <td className="td-fixed">brand2 amount of date **-**</td>
                 <td className="td-fixed">brand3 amount of date **-**</td>
                 <td className="td-fixed">brand4 amount of date **-**</td>
             </tr>
             )
         })}
     </tbody>
 </table>
  }

})
```

and the result should be like this

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `map over an array` and not an object. In your case to render the brand amounts just `create a nested map function` assuming the order of brand values is the same. Also have a look at how the outer map is created. Also you must have a `return statement` in you react class .

```js
var App =  React.createClass({

  render() {
    const data1=[{data1result:[{brand:"brand1"},{brand:"brand2"},{brand:"brand3"},{brand:"brand4"}]}];

    const data2=[{data2result:[{date:"12-01",details:[{amount:24250,brand:"brand1"},{amount:68350,brand:"brand2"},{amount:60,brand:"brand3"},{amount:11078,brand:"brand4"}]},{date:"12-02",details:[{amount:27340,brand:"brand1"},{amount:16500,brand:"brand2"},{amount:210,brand:"brand3"},{amount:23229,brand:"brand4"}]}]}];

    return (
   <table>
     <thead>
       <tr>
           <th></th>
           {
               data1[0].data1result.map(function(i) {
                 return <th>{i.brand}</th>;
               })
             }
       </tr>
     </thead>

     <tbody>
         {data2[0].data2result.map(function(a) {

           return (
             <tr className="salesTarget">
                 <td className="td-fixed"><b>{a.date}</b></td>
                     
                    {a.details.map(function(item){
                        return (
                            <td className="td-fixed">{item.amount}</td>
                 
                        )
                    })}
                 
             </tr>
             )
         })}
     </tbody>
 </table>
    )
  }

})
  
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: I have updated data with minified version to emphasis on `render` and updtaed logic. If edit is not required, please roll it back.

Comment: thank you all for the wonderful solution, really appreciated it. Though can I ask if its posible to add all brands in that particular date?

Comment: @kcNeko *if its possible?* **Yes**. It is possible, but I'd request you to take current answers (*all answers*) and try to deduce solution. Try/Play with them and then if you get stuck, post another question and you will get solution. Try to break problem into smaller sections and solve them individually. This will take sometime, but you will learn how to do certain stuff and in turn you'll help someone. So best of luck :-)

Answer (score 1):

Adding a `map` to your `data2result[].details`, you should be able to render the columns for each brand:

```
export default React.createClass({

  render() {
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th></th>
          {
            data1.map(function(i) {
              return <th>{ i.data1result.brand }</th>;
            })
          }
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        {
          data2.map(function(a) {
            return (
              <tr className="salesTarget">
                <td className="td-fixed"><b>{ a.data2result.date }</b></td>

                {
                  a.details.map(function(b) {
                    <td className="td-fixed">{ b.amount }</td>
                  })
                }
            </tr>
            )
          })
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  }
})
```

Comment: Its incorrect, a.details will be undefined since it is an object of a.data2result event a.data2result.date will give you undefiend

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

Note: This answer just address part of processing data and not binding values to React UI

```js
const data1=[{data1result:[{brand:"brand1"},{brand:"brand2"},{brand:"brand3"},{brand:"brand4"}]}];

const data2=[{data2result:[{date:"12-01",details:[{amount:24250,brand:"brand1"},{amount:68350,brand:"brand2"},{amount:60,brand:"brand3"},{amount:11078,brand:"brand4"}]},{date:"12-02",details:[{amount:27340,brand:"brand1"},{amount:16500,brand:"brand2"},{amount:210,brand:"brand3"},{amount:23229,brand:"brand4"}]}]}];
  
var result = {};
data1[0].data1result.forEach(function(brand){
  data2[0].data2result.forEach(function(res){
    result[res.date] = result[res.date] || {};
    var amount = res.details.reduce(function(p,c){
      p += c.brand === brand.brand ? c.amount : 0;
      return p;
    }, 0)
    if(amount > 0)
      result[res.date][brand.brand] = amount;
  })
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
export default React.createClass({

render() {
    <table>
      <thead>
         <tr>
           <th></th>
           {
              data1[0].data1result.map(function(i) {
                return <th>{ i.brand }</th>;
              })
           }
        </tr>
       </thead>

       <tbody>
        {
           data2[0].data2result.map(function(a) {
              return (
                 <tr className="salesTarget">
                    <td className="td-fixed"><b>{ a.date }</b></td>
                    {
                       a.details.map(function(b) {
                           <td className="td-fixed">{ b.amount }</td> 
                       })
                    }
                 </tr>
              )
           })
        }
       </tbody>
    </table>
   }
})
```